# How to export bundle from local project in symfony 2.1 to github

Tags: git, github, symfony-2.1

I'd like to export my bundle (not whole project) from *symfony 2.1* to my github account for community use.

A good example that I mean it is https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle

Can anyone give me further advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read [Best Practices for Reusable Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html) and [article about bundle configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) for sure.

Basically you should move stuff for example: from `src/YourBundlePrefix/YourBundle` into separate directory/github repository.

Then you should create composer.json for that repository (you can check how it looks like in others bundles) and add bundle to [packagist.org](http://packagist.org/). After those steps you should update your application composer.json so your bundle can be used and downloaded into vendor dir.

Comment: Thank You for giving some advice. I'm newbie in Symfony 2 and some steps are more taught then the others.